# Mocked bean in spring unit test not wired to AutoWired dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-boot-test, springmockito

I am trying to write unit test for a class which has an Autowired dependency.

```
public class User {

@Autowired
private ServiceContext serviceContext;

User() {}

public String getToken() {
    return serviceContext.getToken();
}
```

My Unit Test class to test getToken() method

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserTest() {

  @MockBean
  private ServiceContext serviceContext;

  @BeforeTest
  private void setup() {
  when(serviceContext.getToken()).thenReturn("Token");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
  User user = new User();
  assertEquals(user.getToken(), "Token");
  }
}
```

When I run this test, there is a NullPointerException in `getToken()` of `User` . It says the `serviceContext` variable is null.

Why cant the mock bean which I created in the test be autowired to the dependency in User class ?

I also tried this test code -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserTest() {

  @MockBean
  private ServiceContext serviceContext;

  @InjectMocks
  User useer = new User();

  @BeforeTest
  private void setup() {
  when(serviceContext.getToken()).thenReturn("Token");
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
  assertEquals(user.getToken(), "Token");
  }
}
```

This also gives a NullPointerException saying that the `serviceContext` dependency in `User` class is null.

How do I unit test my User class methods using a `mocked ServiceContext` bean and wiring it to the `User` objects ?

I am using annotation based spring configuration and dont want to start the spring container to test this.

For running my application, I am using this-

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApiProperties.class)
public class ServiceConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
  ServiceContext serviceContext(ApiProperties properties, Parameter param) {
    final ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext(properties, param);
    return serviceContext;
  }
```

Do I need to add this class in my `@SpringBootTest` ?

Answer (score 1):

How does spring know which context should be created?

You've only defined that the test should run with spring, but spring has no clue from where to load the configurations.

You should use `@SpringBootTest` annotation if you want to rely on spring boot configuration resolution rules or at some `@ContextConfiguration` to specify manually the configurations to load.

Comment: I am a newbie to spring. Could you please share some pointers about what should I use as classes in `@SpringBootTest` or `@ContextConfiguration` ?

Comment: You should really read about this, its a broad topic well beyond of SO format. In two words, its the way to specify what exactly should be loaded (spring has to resolve the beans somehow). To start with, try @SpringBootTest without parameters.

Comment: All-in-all, you can start reading here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: So I have a configuration annotated class which declares the `ServiceContext` bean. Edited my question with that part of code.

Comment: To put it simple, class UserTest is not a valid spring boot test because it lacks one of the annotations that I've mentioned in the answer. The application context starts without beans at all (they're loaded from configurations that are not specified), so it has nothing to Autowire

Comment: I cannot use `@SpringBootTest(ServiceConfiguration.class)`  as it will create all @Bean defined in its class. Is there a more trivial way of doing that ?

Comment: Well if you want a spring test it should load some beans otherwise why to use spring at all. You can create a,custom configuration for test if you wosh though.but you have to specify what configuration should be loaded at minimum as i said above